# How to add a primary (Surrogate) key from one table into a foreign key of another table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design

I am trying to add my CustId(Primary Key) from Customers table into CustID(Foreign Key) from CustomerAddress Table. But I am unable to add the foreign key automatically. what should i do. Below is my schema (I copied it from my SQL Server Instance)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] 
(
           [CustId]           INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
           [FirstName]        NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
           [MiddleName]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [LastName]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            [Salutation]       NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
            [Position]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [OrganizationType] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [PhoneNumber]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            [Ext]              NCHAR (10)    NULL,
            [FaxNumber]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [CellNumber]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [EmailAddress]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            [EmailPermission]  NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
            [Password]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustId] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerAddress] 
(
            [AddressID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
            [CustID]           INT,
            [OrganizationName] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            [Division]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [Department]       NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
            [BuildingRoom]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [Street]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [City]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [POBox]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [Province]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
            [PostalCode]       NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
            [Country]          NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
            [AddressType]      CHAR (10)     NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressID]),
            CONSTRAINT [FK_CustID] FOREIGN KEY ([CustID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers] ([CustId])
);
```

C# code for inserting data:

```
public int AddCustomerDeliveryAddress(CustomerAddressBLL NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL)
{
            string sql = string.Format(@"Insert into CustomerAddress (OrganizationName,Division,Department,BuildingRoom,Street,City,POBox,Province,PostalCode,Country,AddressType)
                        Values(@OrganizationName,@Division,@Department,@BuildingRoom,@Street,@City,@POBox,@Province,@PostalCode,@Country,@AddressType)");

            db.AddParameter("@OrganizationName", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Organization);
            db.AddParameter("@Division", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Division);
            db.AddParameter("@Department", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Department);
            db.AddParameter("@BuildingRoom", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.BuildingRoom);
            db.AddParameter("@Street", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Street);
            db.AddParameter("@City", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.City);
            db.AddParameter("@POBox", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.PoBox);
            db.AddParameter("@Province", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Province);
            db.AddParameter("@PostalCode", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.PostalCode);
            db.AddParameter("@Country", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.Country);
            db.AddParameter("@AddressType", NewCustomerDeliveryAddressBLL.AddressType);

            return db.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: I am adding these values using a registration form.

Comment: The structure seems fine as far as I can see - what's your issue, what's your actual **question** ?

Comment: @marc_s I want to add the same Foreignkey value into the CustID from CustomerAddress based on the value of CustID in the Customers Table automatically. as i don't know what value to give in the foreign key table

Comment: Then please show us how you're inserting the data into `Customer` and into `CustomerAddress`! Are you using a T-SQL stored procedure? Some other code? Raw C#/ADO.NET or something else? Entity Framework perhaps? You need to **show us!** We can't see your screen nor read your mind ....

Comment: Its a 3 tier Web Application I am using Classes for both Customer and CustomerAddress each class execute a simple ADO.NET Query.

Comment: You still haven't told us in **what programming language** this is done! C#? VB.NET? Ruby? PHP?

Comment: I am Sorry. Its in C# . I have added my Method that inserts data into the customerAddress table. Data enters Correctly into the Customer Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it in "pure" T-SQL, you need to use code something like this:

```
-- declare variable for your identity
DECLARE @NewCustId INT;

-- insert into your Customers table
INSERT INTO dbo.Customers([FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], ......)
VALUES ('John', 'Robert', 'Doe', ........);

-- get the newly inserted Identity value
SET @NewCustId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- insert into CustomerAddress table
INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerAddress ([CustID], [OrganizationName], [Division], ......)
VALUES(@NewCustId, 'Orgname', 'Division', .....)
```

**Update:** OK, it's C# code - you need to change it to include `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at the end:

```
string sql = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO dbo.CustomerAddress (OrganizationName, Division, Department, BuildingRoom, Street, City, POBox, Province, PostalCode, Country, AddressType)
                             VALUES (@OrganizationName, @Division, @Department, @BuildingRoom, @Street, @City, @POBox, @Province, @PostalCode, @Country, @AddressType); 
                             SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();");
```

and the use this call:

```
int newCustId = (int)db.ExecuteScalar(sql);
```

so you now get back the `NewCustID` from your `INSERT` call - now use that value in the **second** insert you need to insert your data into `CustomerAddress`